# How to receive push notifications on Xamarin.forms using Parse

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform, push-notification, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I followed the parse tutorial there : 
http://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#push-on-xamarin-android

But i didnt received any push notification

A part about the Android configuration is there : http://docs.parseplatform.org/tutorials/android-push-notifications/

But i dont really understand what's happening after the "REGISTER DEVICE FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS" section because in Xamarin.forms, I dont have an Application.cs

I tried to put this code into the App.cs file but I cant override the OnCreate method (as described in the tutorial)
It didnt worked into the init of App.cs

Then, I tried to create a new class into my Android project named "ParseApplication" :

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Parse;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Application(Name = "fr.MyCompany.MyApp.ParseApplication")]
    class ParseApplication : Application
    {
        public ParseApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip)
            : base(handle, ownerShip)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
            {
                ApplicationId = Constants.ParseApplicationId,
                WindowsKey = Constants.ParseWindowsKey,
                Server = Constants.ParseServer
            });
            ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += ParsePush.DefaultParsePushNotificationReceivedHandler;
            ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.0.5"
          package="fr.MyCompany.MyApp" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="6">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/logo">
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
  <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
      <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

      <!--
IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
-->
      <category android:name="fr.MyCompany.MyApp" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

  <!--
IMPORTANT: Change "YOUR_SENDER_ID" to your GCM Sender Id.
-->
  <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
             android:value="id:XXXXXXXXXXXX" />;
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And it didnt worked...

Look at my pushes :

[image: Sashido Dashboard]

I specify that I dont have Android phone, then i can just try on the Android Emulator (API 26). I hope this is not the problem

Im using parse hosted by Sashido

Thanks

**EDIT**

I just saw that the line "`ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveAsync();`" didnt saved the deviceToken :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all the documentation you've read its about Xamarin.Android not Xamarin.Forms , thats why you can't find the OnCreate method . If you're going for Xamarin.Forms you'll need to implement Push Notifications on both Android and iOS platforms separately. I'm trying to do the same thing I'm stuck too , if there was a clear sample of how to implement Push Notifications from with Parse (or other BaaS using Parse) that'd be great !